# Moderators or old timers: what do you foresee regarding the future of Lifehacks SE?

Tags: discussion

As a relative newcomer to Lifehacks SE I see there has been lots of discussion regarding scope, question and answer quality, and similar. What I would really like to know from you moderators and old timers: *What do you foresee in the future for Lifehacks SE, based upon your expectations and experience when creating/supporting/moderating this site?*

Beside the initial shift and precision of the scope, do you see any tendency lately that you like or dislike, and what is your thoughts on how to make Lifehacks into a really good SE site? Or has the train already left the station, so to speak?

Comment: Out of curiosity - do you have a goal for this discussion? Where did you intend to take it?

Comment: It kind of felt like a natural extension to the ongoing site evaluation, and for me (and possibly others) as newcomers it is interesting to get a status quo on where we all are as a community, and the current direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We aren't progressing forward as much as I would like. We need to better define our scope so that we will always know which questions are on/off-topic. We also need to decide which answers are fit to be on this site. What is a life hack? Should we allow conventional answers? These are discussions that we have held earlier in this site's beta, but we never really got a clear decision on. I think that we are a long way from graduating, and that to reach that goal, we need to do a lot of work. I do agree with Mooseman that getting a clear scope to go into our help center should be our next step. I think that things will start to fall into place once that happens.

One last thing we need is more traffic. We don't even average two questions per day right now, even though we are getting over 5,000 visitors a day. I also think that getting our scope defined will help fix this problem because people may not be as scared to ask without getting their question closed.

Answer (score 7):

I think we're heading in the right direction. We do, however, have conflicting views on our scope throughout meta discussions. This makes it difficult for users, especially those new, to say "I know this is on-topic" or "This is off-topic".

At some point in the near future I will be creating a meta discussion for this purpose. Creating a final scope that can be displayed on our [tour page](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour) is an important next step.

Comment: I haven't seen that meta discussion, yet. And I, amongst others, am leaning more and more towards broadening the scope, somehow...