# Why is our definition of "lifehack" so obscure?

Tags: discussion, scope, definition

I discovered Lifehacks a few weeks ago and loved the idea. I posted a question, started to tell a friend about it, and then my first question got closed as "off-topic". ...I decided not to tell my friend.

I like the idea. There aren't any other Stack Exchange communities that encapsulate anything similar. But the moderators are preventing it from becoming what everyone wants it to be.

[Google says that a Lifehack is](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Alifehack):

> A strategy or technique adopted in order to manage one's time and daily activities in a more efficient way.

**This isn't up for debate**–this is what the dictionary says it is. This is what people think of when they hear "lifehack".

However, [the manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto) appends phrases like:

> - solve an everyday problem in **unexpected ways**
> - **unexpected** solutions to the **stubborn** problems
> - A life hack is a seemingly **intractable**, stubborn problem
> - solved by thinking **"outside the box"**.

and applies contrived restrictions like:

> it is NOT about…
>
> - conventional "how to…" questions about skills that can **commonly** be
>     learned elsewhere;
> - using products in the way they were designed to be
>     used (e.g. **keyboard shortcuts**, obscure features, how to get your
>     smartphone to do {x});
> - "mind hacks" including **personal productivity** & **self-improvement tips**, memorization & learning **techniques**, etc;

That last bullet point defining what NOT to do is darn close to BEING Google's definition. [This discussion](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/saving-lifehacks-can-we-make-this-a-topic-space-instead-of-a-vague-buzzword) links to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_hacking) that even mentions "computer shortcuts" in the first sentence–but *keyboard shortcuts aren't allowed*?! It's akin to creating a landscaping SE and prohibiting asking about plants.

Literally [the most upvoted answer on the whole site](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/2091/15) is in direct violation of the second bullet, but got deemed "OK" because it's not common knowledge. Maybe we can reword it to just prohibit common knowledge?

I suspect that the source of the restrictions stems from this assumption I see [again](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1187/10388) and [again](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2431/10388):

> we cannot create a catch-all site about everything

but a Lifehack is inherently *about life*. How can this site NOT be about everything? **What's wrong with hacking everything**? What do we gain by down-voting and closing so many questions?

[I've read that](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2558/10388) we get 5000 visitors but not even 2 questions every day. *[The Lean Startup](http://theleanstartup.com/book)* hammers in the fact that you never know what your product is. You need to be free to pivot. If 5000 customers came into your store but only 2 of them bought anything, wouldn't you try to figure out what the other 4998 people came in looking for?

**Why does the scope need to be so obscure**?

Comment: You say "This isn't up for debate" as if Google were the ultimate arbiter of the English Language.  It is the community on this site that defines what a Lifehack is and is not.

Comment: The referenced sentence "Google says ..." is kind of vague, but is actually based on the article on [lifehack from Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lifehack). So it has some validity, besides being found here and there...

Answer (score 7):

A dictionary doesn't define what a community is about, and more importantly, it doesn't it *redefine* the purpose and type of content for which Stack Exchange was created. Stack Exchange was designed with a very specific focus in mind, somewhat different than a typical discussion forum. Sites center on a quantifiable, specific area of expertise by asking singularly answerable questions. We don't guarantee you can ask a question about anything you want on a site, and we don't create sites about "everything".

When a *Lifehacks* site was proposed, it wasn't exactly the dictionary definition of a subject we would likely host. If we wanted a site on this subject, we would have to narrow down the scope to what we *can* handle and run with it. But we wouldn't have created a site about anything in life or how to be more efficient at anything. That's just not what we do.

When you have an idea for a site, you pick the subject space; then you determine if Stack Exchange is the right tool for the job… and ***then*** find the best possible title to fit it. But the title you chose doesn't wholly rule the scope of the site. You wouldn't [go to DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com) and ask *"What color should I paint my walls?",* yet that is the very *definition* of "Home Improvement." That type of question just doesn't fit the *purpose* for which Stack Exchange was created.

When we pick the sites that can work on this network, we have some tough choices to make — you can either stick to subjects that only have objective answers like *"will this compile?",* or you can *expand* into much more diverse topic space, understanding the limitations of how these sites are designed to work. We chose the later.

Comment: Who is the "we" in "That's just not what we do"–SE or the Lifehacks community? Is there a set of rules somewhere that I can read for myself?

Comment: @adamdport *We* in this case refers more to the Stack Exchange way of doing things than this site specifically. I would suggest starting with the links under the 'help' menu at the top of this site.

Answer (score 1):

> A strategy or technique adopted in order to manage one's time and daily activities in a more efficient way.

That's just  a *tip* or a *way* of doing things.  Not everything is a hack.  Using the term *hack* implies an unexpected, innovative, or improvised workaround, often ugly but nevertheless effective.